Save authorized draft in valid document (10.00 SQL)
I am trying to save an authorized Stock Transfer draft into a valid document. In my organization we work with lots (batches) and locations. I understand that the SaveDocumentToDraft() method is executed in the draft and the valid document should be saved (prior to authorization). The problem is that it shows me the following error:

1470000839 - You cannot specify serial or batch numbers only; you must also specify the issuing bin locations for document row 1


In advance, thank you very much for your help.
I attach the code that I am using to carry out the process:
Private Sub SolicitudTrasladoStock(draftDocEntry As Integer)
    'Obtener el borrador existente
    Dim draft As SAPbobsCOM.StockTransfer
    draft = CType(oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oStockTransferDraft), SAPbobsCOM.StockTransfer)

    If draft.GetByKey(draftDocEntry) Then
        Try
            If draft.SaveDraftToDocument() <> 0 Then
                Dim errorCode As Integer
                Dim errorMsg As String = ""
                oCompany.GetLastError(errorCode, errorMsg)
                MessageBox.Show("Error al crear la transferencia de stock: " & errorMsg, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Transferencia de stock creada con éxito.", "Éxito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Excepción al agregar la transferencia: " & ex.Message, "Excepción", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No se encontró el borrador con DocEntry: " & draftDocEntry, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End Sub

